# Python Exception UnicodeDecodeError refuses to print custom message even when added to args

Tags: python, exception, stdout

I'm using python 3+ and I'm trying to add a custom message to the error.args of UnicodeEDecodeError which isn't being shown in the output

This works as expected, catches the error, adds the additional string as tuple and it's in the output:

```
    try:
        total = 13 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as error:
        error.args += ("This is my error",)
        raise
```

This, however doesn't. I just get the UnicodeDecodeError message and no extra string.

```
    try:
        json_data = json.load(data_file)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as error:
        error.args += ("This is my error",)
        raise
```

I've tried adding the message in some different ways, but no luck:

```
    #error.args = error.args + ("This is an error - print it!!",)
    #e.args = (e.args if e.args else tuple()) + ('Custom message',)
```

Output with no additional msg:

```
 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 308: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/my_python.py", line 144, in <module>
    my_python(event, {})
  File "src/my_python.py", line 73, in my_python
    json_data = json.load(data_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 308: invalid start byte
```

Obvs I printed error.args to screen for both Exceptions and for the divisionByZero I get this: `('division by zero', 'This is my error')` but when I print error.args for UnicodeDecodeError it's got a lot more info: the contents of the file, Loads of metadata then the UnicodeDecodeError and my string at the end. But still doesn't print it to output.

Is this because UnicodeDecodeError is fussy/built differently for some reason? Any help/reasoning is greatly appreciated since I've spent far too long on this already. :D